# How can I fill white spaces in two column when I have minipage?

Tags: minipage, two-column

I am writing an article in two column and I am using the `minipage` environment. The problem is that in the column where there is the `minipage` any text fills the white space ? Why this happens ? I tried to reduce the height of the `minipage` but I couldn't do it. I tried also with `\vfill`

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \begin{minipage}[c][6cm][t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{0.9\linewidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[]
                \node[draw=none,fill=none,scale=1.0] at (0,0)  {\input{figures/case1_macro.tikz}};
                \node[draw=none,fill=none,scale=0.4] at (0,-4) {\includegraphics[]{figures/case1_macro.pdf}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \captionof{figure}{\label{fig:case_1}Example of a beam subjected to flexion solved with the FE$^2$ multi-scale method.}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[c][6cm][t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \vspace{1.5cm}
        \centering
        \resizebox{0.9\linewidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[]
                \node[draw=none,fill=none,scale=1.0] at (0,0)  {\input{figures/case1_micro.tikz}};
                \node[draw=none,fill=none,scale=0.2] at (0,-3) {\includegraphics[]{figures/case1_micro.pdf}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \captionof{figure}{\label{fig:case_1}Example of a beam subjected to flexion solved with the FE$^2$ multi-scale method.}
    \end{minipage}
    \vfill
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: You should have a look at `wrapfigure`.

Comment: thanks @JouleV ! good Idea, I tried something simpler, only changing the `figure` arguments to `\begin{figure}[!h] ... ` has work. I will post that solution.

Comment: don't use `\resizebox` here it is not needed to scale the tikz and just scales the caption to an inconsistent font size.

Answer (score 1):

Specify `[t]` floating, but also set the layout parameters so LaTeX will allow "top" floats to mostly fill the column, leaving very little text:

```
\renewcommand\topfraction{.9}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.1}% 1-\topfraction
```

The default parameters are unusually restrictive.

Using `[h]` placement leads to hassle where you have to keep manually editing the document to make the figure come out right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `figure` arguments. Setting :

\begin{figure}[!h]
   ...
   \end{figure}

Solves the problem.

[image]

Comment: `[!h]` almost always generates a warning and latex changes it to `[!ht]` to give itself a chance. Looking at your image I suspect that is what happened here and that you got a top float setting so it would be better to use `[t]`